# What happened to Adventure Cards?

Tags: savage-worlds

I kept seeing references to adventure cards and the adventure deck, then I noticed PEG used to sell a deck of adventure cards. Lots of people seemed to like it, but I can't find it for sale anymore.

Does anyone know the fate of this product? Why was it withdrawn? And where can I get something similar (can be fan made) for a fantasy game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cards are still for sale and haven't gone out of stock to my knowledge.  You can get them here...

http://www.studio2publishing.com/shop/product_info.php?cPath=25_161&products_id=3356

or also here for 10% off with the ILoveBrains code...

http://beautifulbrainsonline.com/products-page/gaming-aids/savage-worlds-action-adventure-decks/

The cards were never removed nor invalidated because of Savage Worlds Deluxe.

Comment: Good answer, Clint! Thanks for the links and welcome to the site!

Comment: I kept filtering off the action cards because I could use a regular deck, but here it is. Thanks! I just wish they'd sell it separately, I already have a deck of mini playing cards that is neat to drag around.

Comment: Indeed you're right.  My pack arrived within a week.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Those cards are a lot of fun. I'm sad I can't find a deck myself either.

I heard that PEG removed them as they were releasing the Savage Worlds Deluxe Edition which changed the rules slightly, but enough to invalidate the mechanics on several cards.

They may rerelease the cards with updated rules in future.

You can buy a deck of blank cards (system cards* are good) and write your own. Many of the cards are single-use edges, particularly Wild Card edges. Some give the each player another bennie, but give the GM an advantage at the same time (giant monster, reinforcements, etc.) Others are player-induced NPC actions (villain gives a monologue, distracting him.)

<sup>* System cards are also known as "index cards" in some countries.</sup>

Comment: Deck of blank cards? Never heard of. Where do I find those?

Comment: From office supply stores. They're just lined cards used for filing systems. They don't look professional in the slightest, but can serve your purpose.

Comment: "Index cards". I've edited the answer to include the NA name for these.

Comment: That's a neat idea! I found some fan made adventure cards too, I should be able to print them on regular paper and glue them to the index cards to have it uniform.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the PDF from the [PEG](http://www.studio2publishing.com/shop/product_info.php?products_id=3356) site but [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982817533) seam to still have some of the physical cards. I can't see any official announcement but PEG do tend to let stock dry up before releasing new stuff, so I expect that there will be a new lot in the near future.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the few things I don't like about PEG.  They have a lot of product lines that have been out of print for a while, and seem to be very slow to reprint.